# Retrieving GPS Information from DJI Windows SDK for Mavic Air

Tags: windows, gps, dji-sdk

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on a project where I need to retrieve GPS data from my DJI Mavic Air drone. I've been exploring the DJI Windows SDK, but I'm unsure about its capabilities in this regard.

Here is the DJI Windows SDK [documention](https://developer.dji.com/windows-sdk/documentation/introduction/index.html).

Is it possible to get GPS coordinates (latitude, longitude) from the Mavic Air using the DJI Windows SDK?

If yes, could someone provide a brief overview or point me to the relevant documentation or methods within the SDK that handle this?

If the Windows SDK doesn't support this directly, are there any workarounds or alternative SDKs I should consider?

I appreciate any guidance or references. Thank you in advance!

I started by exploring the DJI Windows SDK documentation, specifically looking into classes and methods that might relate to GPS or telemetry data. I was expecting to find straightforward methods or properties that would allow me to access the drone's current GPS coordinates.

However, while I found references to geographical coordinates in the documentation, it wasn't clear to me how to implement this in practice. I tried searching for sample code or examples related to the Mavic Air and the DJI Windows SDK, but my searches didn't yield any concrete results.